# Как правильно установить Git на OS X

Tags: git, macos

С установкой Git на OS X есть проблема: он уже установлен в системе и просто так его не обновить. При каждом обновлении ОС устанавливает его заново.

Например, на момент написания этого вопроса, актуальной версией Git является 2.5.1. А в OS X Yosemite зашит 2.3.2.

При установке новой версии через Homebrew она все равно остается недоступной.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Установка «с нуля»

1. Устанавливаем Git, например через Homebrew

   ```
   $ brew install git
   ```
2. Проверяем текущую версию Git

   ```
   $ git --version
   git version 2.4.9 (Apple Git-60)
   ```

   Если вы видите "Apple Git", значит используется старая версия. Проверим, где установлена используемая версия Git.

   ```
   $ which git
   /usr/bin/git
   ```

   Точно, эта версия ставится вместе с системой. А та, которая нам нужна, и которая установлена homebrew, находится в `/usr/local/bin/git`. Почему выбирается не она? Вероятнее всего потому, что путь к ней находится дальше в переменной окружения `$PATH`.

   ```
   echo $PATH
   ```
3. Меняем `$PATH`

   В переменной `$PATH` хранятся пути к папкам, разделённые двоеточиями. Когда вы хотите запустить какую-то программу по имени (а не по полному пути), поиск происходит во всех этих папках по очереди, слева направо. Переменная задаётся в файле `~/.bashrc` (или `~/.zshrc` и т.п., в зависимости от используемой оболочки). Откройте его и найдите примерно такую строку:

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
   ```

   Поставьте `/usr/local/bin` раньше, чем `/usr/bin`:

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
   ```

   Перезапустите оболочку:

   ```
   bash
   $ git --version
   git version 2.10.1

   $ which git
   /usr/local/bin/git
   ```

   Ура, работает!

Comment: *Переименовываем эту папку* — файл, наверно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: спасибо, перепутал. Кстати, а вы на метку подписаны?

Comment: *which git* — кстати, а переменная окружения `$PATH` в *apple/macos* разве не содержит `/usr/local/bin` **до** `/usr/bin`? // *а вы на метку подписаны?* — да, метка *git* у меня в избранных. но от почтовых уведомлений я давно отказался из-за их неоперативности.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: у меня такой порядок в `$PATH`: `/usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin`. А что, рекомендуете поменять?

Comment: *у меня такой порядок* — это по умолчанию было? // *рекомендуете поменять?* — ну, если поставить, например, `/usr/local/bin` **раньше** `/usr/bin`, то вашу инструкцию можно значительно сократить и упростить. ведь с помощью `brew` программа `git` наверняка копируется куда-нибудь в район `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: вообще, организация $PATH — тема важная и многим может быть полезна. Может быть, я вопрос задам, а вы подробнее ответите, какой порядок лучше, почему, какие могут быть ситуации, когда это важно? Да, `brew` пишет точно в `usr/local/bin`

Comment: ну, по поводу операционных систем, отличных от *gnu/linux* я могу лишь предполагать. к тому же мне сложно оценивать ситуацию с точки зрения разнообразия всяческих *shell*-ов.

Comment: вы попробуйте сделать описанную мной подмену и «потренироваться» с установкой/обновлением *git*-а (как «родного», так и из репозитория, которым пользуется программа `brew`). если это окажется проще — добавьте новый ответ.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: в OS X по этой части всё точно так же, разве что пакетный менеджер другой.

Comment: *всё точно так же* — ну, я бы не был столь категоричен. обязательно есть «нюансы».

Comment: К сожалению в macOS Sierra этот метод переименовывания /usr/bin/git не работает :( система пишет сообщение **rename /usr/bin/git to /usr/bin/git-apple: Operation not permitted** Есть еще идеи как можно удалить Apple Git ?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin прошло чуть больше года, обновил-таки )))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а я на тот вопрос [попытался ответить](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/577157/178576) «на ощупь» (ведь macos видел только «на расстоянии»). интересно, я попал «пальцем в небо», или «в цель»?