# IDEA: Can't start Git: /usr/bin/git

Tags: git, intellij-idea, macos

Обновил mac os. Теперь пишет следующее:

```
Can't start Git: /usr/bin/git
Probably the path to Git executable is not valid.
```

Выглядит это так:

[image: Как это выглядит]

Добавил новый SSH-ключ через Терминал ([Отсюда и далее](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/)). Пока не помогло. Подскажите, как можно восстановить работоспособность Git в IDEA?

Comment: Просто откройте терминал и выполните `/usr/bin/git --version`. Что в ответ? И ещё `which git`. Оба результата добавьте, пожалуйста к тексту вопроса.

Comment: SSH-ключ тут не должен влиять. GitHub тут тоже не при чём, он не терял работоспособности, потому что GitHub – это сайт в интернете, а у вас IDEA не может найти программу Git.

Comment: Пишет: xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

Comment: Какие варианты?

Comment: Похоже на вот эту проблему: [Invalid active developer path error after upgrading to El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896524/invalid-active-developer-path-error-after-upgrading-to-el-capitan).

Comment: Вместо системного гита поставьте новый: [Как правильно установить Git на OS X](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448150/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-git-%d0%bd%d0%b0-os-x)

Comment: Расскажете, что получилось?

Comment: Отлично, всё сработало. Оформите, пожалуйста, Ваш комментарий как отдельный ответ, чтобы я мог его принять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, в комментариях выяснилось, что после обновления macOS бывает необходимо заново поставить git на компьютер. Вот отличная инструкция, как это сделать:

[Как правильно установить Git на OS X](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448150/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-os-x)